# Apple Script with Terminal Commands

Tags: terminal, applescript

I'm trying to create an application that would automate a couple of Terminal commands. I need the application to open once I drop a file on top of it, run the commands, and close. The sequence of commands is supposed to take a EDL file, run it thru a python script, which in turn results in a CSV file. Everything runs fine, but no CSV file appears.
Here's the script:

```
on open theDroppedItems
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script with command "cd /Applications/Python\\ 2.7"
        do script with command "python EDLtoCSV.py " & theDroppedItems & ""
    end tell
end open
```

What am I doing wrong? Any way of seeing where it goes wrong in the process? Any suggestions?

Comment: `theDroppedItems` is being passed into your script as a list of aliases rather than paths. You need to convert them before feeding them into your `do script` commands.

Comment: And while you're at it, you really don't need to involve Terminal in this process; just use `do shell script` directly from AppleScript.

Comment: Thank you, Patrick. Could you please elaborate on converting theDroppedItems into aliases? I can't seem to find a good article on it.

Comment: You would loop through each alias in `theDroppedItems` and convert it by getting its `POSIX path` property. See the section "Converting Between Path Formats" on this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReferenceFilesandFolders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH34-SW1